# Do custom PC droids start with Basic language and vocabulator by default?

Tags: character-creation, star-wars-saga-edition

I have a player who decided to play a droid, and when I was going through the rules to create custom droids, I couldn't find anywhere what automatic languages they have.

The best aproximations to rules I found were in the Communication subsection within the Accesories section (Core Rulebook, page 193).

> All droids are capable of emitting the sounds necessary to speak
> Binary, a language used by droid an computers [...].
>
> **Vocabulator:** The droid is equipped with a speaker that enables it to emulate speech,
> rather than simply spout machine code. ***This device is standard if the
> droid has ability to speak any language other than binary***.

**Is a custom PC droid able to speak (or, at least, understand) Basic by default, hence owning vocabulator by default too, or do it needs to pay for it?**

**Is there any place in the rules where it's described which are the automatic languages for a droid?**

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I just found the answer where it was more likely to be. I just can't believe I didn't notice back then.

Core Book, page 188, last paragraph of "Droid Traits" section:

> **Automatic Languages:** Binary **plus one language** chosen by the designer
>   (usually Basic).

So, if we follow the rules as written, the vocabulator should be standard in a custom droid.